# Container Template Class - Decreasing Container Size

Tags: templates, segmentation-fault, const-iterator

I've written some code to decrease the capacity of a templated container class. After an element is removed from the container, the erase function checks to see whether or not 25% of the total space is in use, and whether reducing the capacity by half would cause it to be less than the default size I've set. If these two return true, then the downsize function runs. However, if this happens while I'm in the middle of a const_iterator loop, I get a segfault.

edit again: I'm thinking it's because the const_iterator pointer is pointing to the old array and needs to be pointed to the new one created by downsize()...now how to go about doing that...

```
template <class T>
void sorted<T>::downsize(){

  // Run the same process as resize, except
  // in reverse (sort of). 
  int newCapacity = (m_capacity / 2);
  T *temp_array = new T[newCapacity];

  for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
    temp_array[i] = m_data[i];

  // Frees memory, points m_data at the 
  // new, smaller array, sets the capacity
  // to the proper (lower) value.
  delete [] m_data;
  m_data = temp_array;
  setCap(newCapacity);
  cout << "Decreased array capacity to " << newCapacity << "." << endl;  
}


// Implementation of the const_iterator erase method.
template <class T>
typename sorted<T>::const_iterator sorted<T>::erase(const_iterator itr){  

  // This section is reused from game.cpp, a file provided in the
  // Cruno project. It handles erasing the element pointed to
  // by the constant iterator.
  T *end = &m_data[m_capacity];    // one past the end of data
  T *ptr = itr.m_current;        // element to erase

  // to erase element at ptr, shift elements from ptr+1 to 
  // the end of the array down one position
  while ( ptr+1 != end ) {
    *ptr = *(ptr+1);
    ptr++;
  }

  m_size--;

  // Once the element is removed, check to
  // see if a size reduction of the array is
  // necessary.
  // Initialized some new values here to make
  // sure downsize only runs when the correct
  // conditions are met.
  double capCheck = m_capacity;
  double sizeCheck = m_size;
  double usedCheck = (sizeCheck / capCheck);
  int boundCheck = (m_capacity / 2);
  if ((usedCheck <= ONE_FOURTH) && (boundCheck >= DEFAULT_SIZE))
    downsize();

  return itr;
}


// Chunk from main that erases.
int i = 0;
for (itr = x.begin(); itr != x.end(); itr++) {
  if (i < 7) x.erase(itr);
  i++;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent issues with invalidated iterators during an erase loop, you can use:

```
x.erase(itr++);
```

instead of separate increment and increment calls (obviously if you're not erasing everything you loop over you'd need an else case to increment past the non-erased items.) Note this is a case where you need to use post-increment rather than pre-increment.

The whole thing looks a bit inefficient though. The way you convert to an array suggests that it's only going to work with certain container types anyway. If you expect lots of erasing from the middle of the container you might be able to avoid the memory issue by just choosing a different container; list maybe.

If you choose vector, you might find that calling shrink_to_fit is what you want.

Also note that erase has a return value that will point to the (new) location of the element after the erased one.

If you go down the line of returning an iterator to a newly created down-sized version of the container, note that comparing to the original containers end() iterator wouldn't work.

Comment: I don't have much choice as to what kind of container it is, unfortunately. It's for a school project so they gave me this long list of methods / data members and said go implement it like this.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the segfault problem!

What was going on was that my x.end() was using the size of the array (NOT the capacity), where the size is the number of data elements stored in the array, instead of the capacity which is actually the size of the array. So when it was looking for the end of the array, it was seeing it as numerous elements before the actual end.

Now on to more interesting problems!